# Take 10% away from a double Java

Tags: java, double, percentage

I was wondering on how I could take 10% away from a double value in Java? I've tried researching percentages in Java, but it's a bit confusing.

Comment: multiply the value by 0.9 (i.e. 90%) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply 0.1 instead of using percents.

For example:

```
/*Your starting value*/
int x = 100
/* Your percent you want to take away*/
int y = 0.1 /*0.1 is the same as 10%*/
int z = x*y
/* A takes your starting amount and takes away 10% */
int a = x-z
/* a is your answer */
```

A more simple way of doing this would be to multiply by 0.9 (it multiplys by 90%).

```
/*Your starting number*/
int x = 100
/*What you want to take away*/
int y = 0.9
int z = x*y
```

This does take less code and eqations.

Comment: Why make three calculations when one would be enough?

Comment: I didn't get to add that yet.

Comment: I suggest using meaningful identifiers rather than `x`, `y`, and `z`.